# What plugins can I use for WordPress that will allow my premium users to have access to video content?

Tags: wordpress

I want to have a separate part of my WordPress website blocked off only for premium users, this membership area will have training videos. It might be 2 plugins to achieve this, please help me figure out which ones. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new role for premium users 
then use **Content Control – User Access Restriction Plugin**
to specify which content to show to users
https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-control/